# Xtend: evaluate expression directly from a string

Tags: eval, xtend

Is there a possibilty in the Xtend language to evaluate an expression directly from a string, e.g. like `Eval` in Groovy. I want to do something like this in Xtend (the example is from Groovy):

```
import groovy.util.Eval

assert Eval.me('2*5') == 10
```

If there is no built-in way to do this, what would be the most similar alternative to achieve this (if any)?

P.S. Just to be clear: the expression is of course not just a simple math operation (like in the example); in particular, I would like to call my own Xtend function doing some transformation on a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there isn't anything like this in Xtend, so you should probably look for Java libraries that do this.

For example [Java EL](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el.htm) seems like a good standard way for evaluating strings. Since EL 3 there is the [ELProcessor](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ELProcessor.html) which doesn't require JSP anymore and it seems quite easy to use:

> ```
> ELProcessor elp = new ELProcessor();
> elp.defineBean("employee", new Employee("Charlie Brown"));
> String name = elp.eval("employee.name");
> ```

Here is nice [article about the latest features of EL](http://www.baeldung.com/jsf-expression-language-el-3), like lambda expression. The article also contains some examples about collections and how to call external methods.